# How to fix lets encrypt certificate in kubernetes of aws?

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, ssl, amazon-eks, lets-encrypt

I have followed this [digitalocean](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MpovOI5eK58) video and tried setting up lets encrypt in a sample eks cluster.

Their github repo: digitalocean/Kubernetes-Starter-Kit-Developers
At the end of process, only able to see issuer, no certificate or certificate requests.

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-15-131 ~]$ kubectl -n backend get issuer
NAME                READY   AGE
letsencrypt-nginx   True    13m
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-15-131 ~]$ kubectl -n backend get order
No resources found in backend namespace.
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-15-131 ~]$ kubectl -n backend get challenges
No resources found in backend namespace.
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-15-131 ~]$ kubectl -n backend get certificaterequests
No resources found in backend namespace.
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-15-131 ~]$ kubectl -n backend get certificate
No resources found in backend namespace.
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-15-131 ~]$ kubectl -n backend get certificate
No resources found in backend namespace.
```

Steps followed:

Installed Helm: https://helm.sh/docs/intro/install/

Installed helm repo: https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx

full values to list in nginx:
https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/main/charts/ingress-nginx/values.yaml

In the namespace ingress-nginx created, used below helm install.

```
helm install ingress-nginx ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx -n ingress-nginx -f nginx-values.yml

kubectl get all -n ingress-nginx
```

fetch ip/domainname of ingress-nginx-controller service above.

register this ip of loadbalancer svc in route53.

And then ran below deployment.

```
kubectl create ns backend
kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml
kubectl apply -f ingress.yaml
kubectl get ingress -n backend
---wait till the address generated
```

Then installed cert-manager helm chart and CRDs.

```
https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/cert-manager/cert-manager
kubectl apply -f https://github.com/cert-manager/cert-manager/releases/download/v1.7.1/cert-manager.crds.yaml
kubectl get crds
helm repo add jetstack https://charts.jetstack.io
helm repo update
kubectl create ns cert-manager
helm install cert-manager -n cert-manager --version v1.7.1 jetstack/cert-manager -f cert-manager-values.yaml
kubectl apply -f issuer.yaml
```

Reconfigured nginx ingress by enabling tls and applied.

```
kubectl apply -f ingress.yaml
```

My [files](https://github.com/uday1kiran/logs/tree/master/letsencrypt) used above, please ignore the _template files.

Even, I followed this [blogpost](https://www.howtogeek.com/devops/how-to-install-kubernetes-cert-manager-and-configure-lets-encrypt/) now, but got below error when applying ingress.

```
error: resource mapping not found for name: "my-ingress" namespace: "" from "ingress.yml": no matches for kind "Ingress" in version "networking.k8s.io/v1beta1"
ensure CRDs are installed first
```

Answer (score 0):

`networking.k8s.io/v1beta1` was deprecated as of `v1.22`, presuming you are running a cluster on 1.22 or higher?

From the blog post, you should just be able to update the ingress manifest to use the stable `v1` like so:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-staging # your issuer name
    # cert-manager.io/issuer: letsencrypt - if using an issuer
...
```

Other things to check: everything is in the same namespace (issuers are namespace-only, cluster issuers can be accessed across namespaces), CertManager is able to connect to LetsEncrypt (example email addresses etc. will block this) - check the CertManager pod logs.